# SSH paramiko if condition on stdout.channel.recv() not working

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm new to python and trying to make automations out of a bunch of unix cmds with paramiko

here is the function I'm trying to use

```
def sendcommand(self, command):
        password ="somestring"
        if self.client is not None:# Check if connection is made previously
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():# Print stdout data
                if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    channel_data = stdout.channel.recv(9999)# Retrieve the first 9999 bytes
                    while stdout.channel.recv_ready():# Retrieve the next 9999 bytes
                        channel_data += stdout.channel.recv(9999)
                    if stdout.channel.closed is False:# Check if stdout is still open
                        stdin.write(password + '\n') 
                        stdin.flush()

                        print(str(_data, "utf8"))# Print as string with utf8 encoding
        else:
            print("Could not open connection.")
```

this function works when I use some sudo command and the shell is waiting for the password, but when I need for exemple to create a user on centos and add a password (the sheel prompts for a new password) this won't wotk as it will feed the sudo password due to

```
if stdout.channel.closed is False:
```

I'm trying to find a way to add an if condition on the stdout stream so that when it asks for the sudo password it feeds the sudo password to stdin and when something else it writes other things, something like:

```
if channel.stdout.read().decode("utf-8").endswith("[sudo] password for user: "):
   stdin.write(password2 + '\n') 
   stdin.flush()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you realize that what you are trying to implement is hard, because the commands you are trying to automate are *designed to resist the automation at all costs*? That should suggest you something... + Related question: [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment @MartinPrikryl, I realise it can be tricky, I managed to make it work using a new syntax for adding user which do not prompt for input : useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 "password") "username", but I would really appreciate if anyone could help understand why I can't get the if condition to work in my exemple? thank you